# WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet 4.5 .net Framework Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Once users are authenticate with azure it redirects to the index page however does not reflect on the application it self.

Project Page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-openId-connect-with-ad-fs

WebConfig:
[image]

Startup.Auth:
[image]

AccountController:
[image]

Once logged in the user does not show Authenticated:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Web Config:
 <add key="ida:ClientId" value="[CLientID]" />
 <add key="ida:Tenant" value="Enter tenant name, e.g. .onmicrosoft.com" />
 <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
 <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="[Replace this with Redirect URI]" />

Comment: Startup.Auth: 

        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

Comment: HomeController:

namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers
{
    
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View((User as ClaimsPrincipal).Claims);
            //return View();
        }

Comment: Index Page:

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"; }

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
    <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <td>UserId:</td>
        <td>@User.Identity.Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Currently Logged in?</td>
        <td>@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated</td>
    </tr>